# How do you send an input into a continuous loop? (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I have a problem, lets say I have a continuous while loop, and inside there is a variable x that is used in some calculation. How do I send an input from the keyboard to the loop to change the variable x within the loop without stopping the loop in C++? 
Thanks

Comment: You want non blocking keyboard input. I think that is very OS dependent, so you should specify what platform you're using.

Comment: Could you not just check some kind of keyboard buffer, or interrupt in your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running linux, your best bet is using [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/). The [S-lang](http://www.jedsoft.org/slang/) library is also used by some, but I have no experience with it. Multithreading is not required.

Comment: But what about signals? Can't I use signals to change the variables inside a loop that is already running?

Comment: Of course, you could probably use SIGALRM to poll the keyboard, but why not just poll the keyboard from within the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably multi-threading, a second thread could wait for a keyboard.

Have a look at boost/c++ for details of implementation :
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread.html

Answer (score 1):

**IF** you're in Windows, you can use `GetAsyncKeyState`.  (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx ).  However, if you're not, this won't work (obviously) :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is user-software, I'd go for the multi-threaded approach as mentioned by smichaud.  If it is a tool (and performance isn't an issue), you could read from a file continuously and change that file from outside, as this the simplest implementation.